# VBA Excel Automatic Template Selection

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am writing a VBA script that I want to do smarter mail merge functions with.

Basically, I have 3 word templates that are formatted differently with replacement tags in different places. We'll call these templates 1-3.

I have a table where each row has the necessary replacement data as strings, with a max of 6 strings per row.  To the left of this table, in column B, I have the number of strings in the table listed, and based on this number I want it to choose the correct template.  I think I may have the LeftCell dim configured incorrectly, or my code is choosing a template correctly the first time, but applying it to all the other rows.  If I run the script it always seems to choose the first template.

```
Sub CreateWordDocuments()
Dim CustRow, CustCol, LastRow, LeftCell, TemplRow As Long
Dim DocLoc, TagName, TagValue, TemplName, FileName As String
Dim WordDoc, WordApp As Object
Dim WordContent As Word.Range
With Sheet1

If .Range("B3").Value = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Please select a template from the dropdown list"
    .Range("G3").Select
    Exit Sub
End If
    TemplRow = .Range("B3").Value 'Set Template Row
    TemplName = .Range("G3").Value 'Set Template Name
    DocLoc = Sheet2.Range("F" & TemplRow).Value 'Word Doc Filename

    'Open Word Template
    On Error Resume Next 'If Word is already running
    Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'Launch a new instance of Word
    Err.Clear
    'On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True 'Make the application visible to the user
    End If


    LastRow = .Range("E999").End(xlUp).Row 'Determine last row
    LeftCell = .Range("B" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value
    For CustRow = 8 To LastRow
                If LeftCell = 6 Then
                    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\jhabermann\Desktop\Excel VBA Test Environment\Template 1.docx", ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template
                ElseIf LeftCell = 4 Then
                    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\jhabermann\Desktop\Excel VBA Test Environment\Template 2", ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template
                Else: LeftCell = 3
                    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\jhabermann\Desktop\Excel VBA Test Environment\Template 3.docx", ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template
                End If

                    For CustCol = 5 To 10 'Move through 3 columns
                        TagName = .Cells(7, CustCol).Value  'Tag Name
                        TagValue = .Cells(CustRow, CustCol).Value 'Tag Value
                        With WordDoc.Content.Find
                            .Text = TagName
                            .Replacement.Text = TagValue
                            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
                        End With
                    Next CustCol
    WordDoc.PrintOut
    WordDoc.Close
    Kill (FileName) 'Deletes the Word File just created
Next CustRow
WordApp.Quit

End With
End Sub
```

Ignore the few lines of code regarding b3 and g3, I am saving that for later functionality to perhaps choose different sets of templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move `Leftcell` inside your loop and increment it with every iteration:

```
For CustRow = 8 To LastRow
    LeftCell = .Range("B" & CustRow).Value
            If LeftCell = 6 Then
                Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\jhabermann\Desktop\Excel VBA Test Environment\Template 1.docx", ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template
            ElseIf LeftCell = 4 Then
                Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\jhabermann\Desktop\Excel VBA Test Environment\Template 2", ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template
            Else: LeftCell = 3
                Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\jhabermann\Desktop\Excel VBA Test Environment\Template 3.docx", ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template
            End If

                For CustCol = 5 To 10 'Move through 3 columns
                    TagName = .Cells(7, CustCol).Value  'Tag Name
                    TagValue = .Cells(CustRow, CustCol).Value 'Tag Value
                    With WordDoc.Content.Find
                        .Text = TagName
                        .Replacement.Text = TagValue
                        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
                    End With
                Next CustCol
    WordDoc.PrintOut
    WordDoc.Close
    Kill (FileName) 'Deletes the Word File just created
Next CustRow
```

As a note, not sure what you're doing on that `Else: LeftCell = 3` line - why set `LeftCell` to anything? I think you meant for another `ElseIf` there.

Comment: As far as the last Else, I know I could have kept it shorthand but I felt like looking at that visually might have helped me figure out my issue. Plus as you stated I could just change it to elseif if I ever wanted to add another template.